# jQuery: Display the name of key and value of Json Array

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json array as shown below:

```
var data =[{"id":"1","name1":"avi", "age":"20"},{"id":"2","name1":"suresh","age":"30"}, {"id":"3","name1":"rajesh", "age":"40"}];
```

I can retrive the key value pairs or get the value by key. but here the key's name for the second place(name1) is not constant (could be anything). What I know is I should be able to get the name of key in 2nd position of each array and display its value. This is how I did:

```js
var data =[
{"id":"1","name1":"avi", "age":"20"},
{"id":"2","name1":"suresh","age":"30"},
{"id":"3","name1":"rajesh", "age":"40"}
];

var keys = [];
$.each(data, function(key1, value){
  if(key1 == 0){
    $.each(value, function(k,v){
      keys.push(k);
    });
  }
  console.log(keys[1]+ "::"+value[keys[1]]);   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I could get **result**:

[image]

But I think there is more better and clean way to do. If there is please let me know.

For each object how can I get the respective key value pair by doing something like obj[2].key and obj[2].value ??

Answer (score 0):

If you know the keys you can try

```
for(var i in data)
{
   var name = data[i].name1;
   console.log(name);
}
```

Else link in comment is best option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

Object keys returns the array of object keys

```
var key = Object.keys(obj)[0] //This contains the id
obj[key] //This contains the value
```

Another way without jquery

```
// Code goes here
var data =[
{"id":"1","name1":"avi", "age":"20"},
{"id":"2","name1":"suresh","age":"30"},
{"id":"3","name1":"rajesh", "age":"40"}
];

//Just to get the logic
for(var el in data){

      var obj = data[el];
      var keys = Object.keys(obj); //Returns array of keys

      for(var i in keys){
        var key = keys[i]

        console.log(key+" "+obj[key]);
      }
}
```

here is a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/K4xM1X2xeNSyf3BrBCRs?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the value of object in second location

```
 $.each(data, function(key1, value){
  if(key1===1)
    var x = data[key1];
  }
```

Comment: But objects are non indexed collection, there is no reason all browsers would parse it the same, meaning the unknwon key would still be in the second position. EDIT: in fact in OP's code, data is an array, here you are returning the second item of array, that's not the question

Comment: Ya I am sorry my bad .. Please dont consider this answer

Answer (score 0):

The proprieties of an object doesn't have an order, so you have to change strategy, for example create a key called "name" that contains an array of two values, [name1, avi], where name1 is the dynamic propriety.

```js
var data =[
{"id":"1", "name": ["name1","avi"], "age":"20"},
{"id":"2", "name": ["name2","blabla"],"age":"30"},
{"id":"3", "name": ["name3","hello"], "age":"40"}
];


data.forEach(function(element, index, array){
  document.body.innerHTML += ('the ' + element.name[0] + ' is ' +     element.name[1] + '<br>')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the unknown key and you know the others, you could use [object keys property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (check browser support) and filter it out:

```
var knownKeys = ['id','age'];
var keyName = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(function(k){return knownKeys.indexOf(k) === -1;}).toString(); // >> name1
```

### -jsFiddle-